# SqLite in memory DB and NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, sqlite

I have nhibernate working with an oracle db, and I am trying to use sqlite in memory db to test our query logic. I believe I have read, understood and confirmed every answer on the web concerning this problem, some of them a few times :)

I am getting the SQLite error no such table:
I also don't see any ddl commands on the SchemaExport call

Here are the bits of my setup that I feel are relevant.
This code is all from same method

```
cfg = new Configuration()
.SetProperty(Environment.ReleaseConnections, "on_close")
.SetProperty(Environment.Dialect, typeof(SQLiteDialect).AssemblyQualifiedName)
.SetProperty(Environment.ConnectionDriver, typeof(SQLite20Driver).AssemblyQualifiedName)
.SetProperty(Environment.ConnectionString, "Data Source=:memory:;Version=3;New=True")
.SetProperty(Environment.ProxyFactoryFactoryClass, typeof(ProxyFactoryFactory).AssemblyQualifiedName)
.SetProperty(Environment.ShowSql, "true")
.SetProperty(Environment.ConnectionProvider, typeof(NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider).AssemblyQualifiedName);
cfg.AddAssembly("MyAssembly");
_sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
_session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession();
new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(true, true, false, _session.Connection, Console.Out); <--don't see any ddl commands here
var q = from c in _session.Query<ComponentGroup>()
where !c.IsDiscontinued
select c;
var z = q.ToList(); //<--get error here
```

My .hbm.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping assembly="myassmebly" namespace="myns" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
<class name="ComponentGroup" table="TBL_COMPONENT_GROUP" lazy="true" >
<id name="Id" column="N_COMPONENT_GROUP_ID" type="int">
  <generator class="native" />
</id>
<property name="AssemblyFacilityId" column="N_ASSEMBLY_FACILITY_ID" type="int" not-null="true" />
<property name="Name" column="C_COMPONENT_GROUP_NAME"    type="string" not-null="true" />
<property name="IsDiscontinued" column="N_DISCONTINUED_FLAG" type="bool" not-null="true" />
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My POCO

```
public class ComponentGroup
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int AssemblyFacilityId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsDiscontinued { get; set; }
}
```

The innerexception

```
  InnerException: System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException
   Message=SQLite error
   no such table: TBL_COMPONENT_GROUP
   Source=System.Data.SQLite
   ErrorCode=-2147467259
   StackTrace:
        at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare(SQLiteConnection cnn, String strSql, SQLiteStatement previous, UInt32 timeoutMS, String& strRemain)
        at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.BuildNextCommand()
        at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.GetStatement(Int32 index)
        at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult()
        at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd, CommandBehavior behave)
        at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
        at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
        at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
        at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteReader(IDbCommand cmd)
        at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.GetResultSet(IDbCommand st, Boolean autoDiscoverTypes, Boolean callable, RowSelection selection, ISessionImplementor session)
        at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)
        at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)
        at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters)
```

I'm using NHibernate version 3.1.0.4, System.Date.SQLite version 2.0.50727

Comment: can you check if your hbm.xml mappings are really set to embedded resource?

Comment: its is, same hbm works with an oracle session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the fix is to replace 
new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(true, true, false, _session.Connection, Console.Out);
with
new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(true, true, false, _session.Connection, null);

Really not sure why, but I added code to insert rows into exported table, which worked as expected.

I then put the Console.Out parm back in and got a "Cannot write to a closed TextWriter." error.